# Polly cache policy is not adding values to the cache

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.0, polly

I'm at a loss with using the cache policy from the Polly project.
I've set up all according to the examples, and it basically seems to work.

I've written a unit test, where the value is successfully retrieved, put to the cache and read from the cache on later invocations.
However, when I run the code in the asp.net core context, it's not working as expected. The wrapped action is executed and the value is retrieved. However, the put to cache method is never executed.
I tried to use my own IAsyncCacheProvider, to debug the issue. And its PutAsync method is never called in the asp.net context. It is called though, when running in a unit test.

Here my service configuration

```
services.AddSingleton<IAsyncCacheProvider, MemoryCacheProvider>();
services.AddSingleton<IPolicyRegistry<string>, PolicyRegistry>();
```

And here excerpts from the class causing the issues.

```
public Bar(
            IPolicyRegistry<string> policyRegistry,
            IService service,
            IAsyncCacheProvider cacheProvider)
{
     this.policyRegistry = policyRegistry;
     this.service = service;
     this.cacheProvider = cacheProvider;
}

 public Task<bool> Foo(Guid id)
 {
    var cachePolicy = this.GetPolicy();

    return cachePolicy.ExecuteAsync(
           _ => this.service.Foo(id),
           new Context("policyKey" + id));
 }


private CachePolicy<bool> GetPolicy()
{
    if(!this.policyRegistry.TryGet(PolicyKey, out CachePolicy<bool> policy))
    {
         policy = Policy.CacheAsync<bool>(
         this.cacheProvider.AsyncFor<bool>(),
         TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
         (c, s) => { },
         (c, s) => { },
         (c, s) => { },
         (c, s, e) => { },
         (c, s, e) => { });

         this.policyRegistry.Add(PolicyKey, policy);
   }

   return policy;
}
```

Any ideas, what could cause this behavior? When I put breakpoints, then it never tries to add the return value to the cache. There isn't any exception either.

Comment: A useful next step could be use the [available delegate hooks](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Cache#interacting-with-policy-operation) to log/capture any exceptions that may be occurring.  If CachePolicy encounters an exception, it passes that to the error hooks for logging and then intentionally [swallows it, as described here](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Cache#throws). This is so that caching itself can never bring down the whole app. Does using those delegate to capture any errors provide any useful info?

Comment: I tried that, and these hooks were never called

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found the answer in the source code.

In the class CacheEngine there is the following code.

```
if (ttl.Timespan > TimeSpan.Zero && result != null && !result.Equals(default(TResult)))
  {
  try
  {
      await cacheProvider.PutAsync(cacheKey, result, ttl, cancellationToken, continueOnCapturedContext).ConfigureAwait(continueOnCapturedContext);
      onCachePut(context, cacheKey);
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
       onCachePutError(context, cacheKey, ex);
  }
}
```

So whenever the return value of this service, which is bool, happens to be false, it is not put to the cache because that is actually the default value of the type. In the unit test I happened to use true as the returned value, therefore the cache worked.

Comment: That is correct.  If that is undesirable behaviour in your case, you could switch the return type of the execution to be `bool?`.  Since `default(bool?) == null`, you would be able successfully to cache a return value of `false`.

Comment: May I ask, what was the reasoning behind this? For reference types it seems naturally, but for enums or basic types not necessarily.  I would like to avoid changing the interface just for caching. Is there anyway to override this behavior?

Comment: I see that I can just wrap the execution inside a policy of type bool?. That's a good enough workaround. But I think, that is some information worth to put in the documentation. Thanks for your help

Comment: The original logic was by analogy with the [behaviour of MemoryCache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.caching.memorycache.get). I agree this makes sense for reference types in a way that it may not for value types. [Documented](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/cache#caching-defaulttresult-for-value-types).  We may change this in a future version of Polly.

Comment: This has been fixed in Polly v7: Polly cache policies now cache `default(TResult)` automatically. https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Cache#caching-defaulttresult-for-value-types